# How do I change the modified date of a file in Windows Vista?

Tags: windows, windows-vista

I have a few ZIP files in a folder; I want to change their modified date to three days ago.
How do I do that?

My operating system is Windows Vista.

Answer (score 1):

I'll assume that this is a programming question (even though it isn't). In this case, you would use the `SetFileTime` function of **WinAPI** with your file handle.

```
BOOL WINAPI SetFileTime(
  __in      HANDLE hFile,
  __in_opt  const FILETIME *lpCreationTime,
  __in_opt  const FILETIME *lpLastAccessTime,
  __in_opt  const FILETIME *lpLastWriteTime
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [BulkFileChanger from Nirsoft](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/bulk_file_changer.html) for this purpose.

If you want to change the file time programmatically you can use the [SetFileTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724933%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function. To convert between different time formats you can use [TzSpecificLocalTimeToSystemTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725485%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [SystemTimeToFileTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724948%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). In order to get a handle to the file use [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

[UnxUtils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) is one of many tool sets which has ported the handy (pun intended) `touch` tool with several options and switches:

```
touch --help
Usage: touch [OPTION]... FILE...
Update the access and modification times of each FILE to the current time.

  -a                     change only the access time
  -c                     do not create any files
  -d, --date=STRING      parse STRING and use it instead of current time
  -f                     (ignored)
  -m                     change only the modification time
  -r, --reference=FILE   use this file's times instead of current time
  -t STAMP               use MMDDhhmm[[CC]YY][.ss] instead of current time
      --time=WORD        access -a, atime -a, mtime -m, modify -m, use -a
      --help             display this help and exit
      --version          output version information and exit

STAMP may be used without -t if none of -drt, nor --, are used.
```