# Adjust creation date/time of files already copied?

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive, file-transfer, date, file-attributes

I recently replaced my laptop's hard-disk with a bigger capacity SSD. Windows was re-installed from scratch and then I copied my data to the SSD by putting the old hard-disk in an external USB enclosure (simple Copy-Paste using Windows Explorer).

So far, so good.  However, I just realized that in the process, all of the "Creation dates" were "reset" to the date of the copy, which I didn't notice at first because the "Modified dates" displayed in Windows Explorer had been kept.

I have looked up the issue and found many ways not to make the same mistake again (using xcopy, robocopy, or other tools).  But, **is there a solution that doesn't require deleting all of the files and copying them again,** i.e., is there a way to just change the attributes of the files on the SSD by using the information from the original files that are still present on the external hard disk?

Comment: Requests for a tool are off topic here, and will probably cause this question to be closed.

Comment: Any real solution would invovle copying the files again.  [How you change the modification date of a file has been asked and answered before though.](http://superuser.com/questions/347081/how-do-i-change-the-modified-date-of-a-file-in-windows-vista/347606#347606)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Windows [PowerShell script](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/06/01/use-powershell-to-modify-file-access-time-stamps.aspx) to copy the last-modified-date to the created-date, if that's all you need.

Windows Explorer, though, can be set to display *any* or *all* of the file dates (created, modified and accessed), simply by right-clicking on the header bar, so you could set the display for the particular folder(s) with the erroneous created-date to show modified-date, instead.